# How to use char* with SD library with Arduino?

Tags: arduino

I am writing a data logger and would like to keep the files limited to a specific number of entries. I am trying to write this bit of code in the setup, so that when the Arduino powers on, it will write to a new file just to keep things simple. However, when I try to open the file I can't, although I am not sure why. Can anyone offer any explanation?

```
char *fileName; //global name 
File logFile; //global file 
//everything else is in setup() 
char * topPart = "/Data/Data"; //first part of every file 
char * lowerPart = ".txt"; // jus the extention 
char * itter; //used to hold the char of i later 
fileName = "/Data/Data.txt"; //start with the first file possible.
for(int i=0; i<=100;i++) {
  if(!SD.exists(fileName)) {
    Serial.print("opening file: ");
    Serial.print(fileName);
    logFile = SD.open(fileName, FILE_WRITE);
    if(logFile) {
      logFile.println("I made it");
      Serial.println("in the file");
    }
    if(!logFile) {
      Serial.println("somthing bad");
    }
    break;
  } else {
    itter = (char *)(i+48);
    strcpy(fileName,topPart);
    strcpy(fileName,itter);
    strcpy(fileName,lowerPart);
    Serial.println(i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of problems.

- the construction of `itter` is wrong.
- `strcpy` doesn't append just cpy.

Here is a code example to build your filename. This a basic C program. Remove the #include and main for Arduino, this allows to test on your computer whether the program is ok.

```
#include <string.h> 

#define TOPPART "/Data/Data" 
#define LOWERPART ".txt"

int main(void) {
  char buf[64];
  snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%s%s", TOPPART, LOWERPART);
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    /* here your stuff to check if the filename froml buf exists*/
    snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%s%d%s", TOPPART, i, LOWERPART);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help here, I had never heard of snprintf before but it worked like a charm! have marked this as the answer.